# Runge's approximation

Tags: complex-analysis

Runge's approximation theorem state that:

> Any function holomorphic in a neighborhood of compact set $K \subset \Bbb{C}$,if $K^c$
> is connected,then it can be approximated uniformly by a polynomial on
> $K$.

We may need to use the following fact

if $f(z)$ can be approximated uniformly by polynomial in $z$( in the form $a_nz^n + ...+a_1z +a_0$)  over $K$

$g(z)$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomal in $f(z)$ (polynomial in the form $a_nf^n(z) + ... + a_1f(z) + a_0 $) over $K$

Then $g(z)$ can also be approximated uniformly by a polynomial in $z$ over $K$

I don't know how to prove this fact?It seems to need a diagonal arguement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\let\e\varepsilon$**Notation.**

Given a function $h : K \to \Bbb C$, I will use $\|h\|$ to denote $\sup_{z \in K} |h(z)|$.

---

Fix $\e > 0$. We wish to show that there's a polynomial $p$ such that $$\|g - p\| < \e. \tag{1}$$
First, let $q$ be a polynomial such that $$\|g - q \circ f\| < \frac\e2. \tag{2}$$
(Such a polynomial exists by your hypothesis.)

Now, note that $K' := f(K)$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb C$ since $f$ is continuous. (Why is $f$ continuous?)

In turn, the following subset $$C := \{z \in \Bbb C : |z - w| \leqslant 1 \text{ for some } w \in K'\}$$
is compact.
(The above set is clearly bounded, check that it is closed as well.)

Now, since $q$ is a polynomial, it is continuous on $C$ and hence, uniformly continuous. Thus, there exists $\delta > 0$ with $\delta < 1$ such that $$|q(z) - q(w)| < \frac\e2 \tag{3}$$ whenever $z, w \in C$ with $|z - w| < \delta$.

Now, let $r$ be a polynomial such that $$\|f - r\| < \delta. \tag{4}$$

In particular, $r(z) \in C$ for all $z \in K$. (By definition, we also have $f(z) \in f(K) \subset C$ for all $z \in K$.)

Thus, $(3)$ and $(4)$ apply to give $$\|q \circ f - q \circ r\| < \frac\e2. \tag{5}$$

Combining $(2)$ and $(5)$ now finishes the job since we get $$\|g - q \circ r\| < \e$$ and the fact that the composition of polynomials is again a polynomial.